# DeGiorgi oscillation lemma

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Where can I find a proof of the following result?

> Let $u$ be a subsolution of $$\mathrm{div}(A(x)\nabla u) = 0,$$
>   where $A$ is bounded, measurable and uniformly elliptic ($C^{-1}\mathrm{Id} \le A(x) \le C \mathrm{Id}$) in $B(0,1)$ such that 
>   $u \le 1$ and $|\{ u \le 0\}| =a>0$. Then $$\sup_{B_{1/2}}u \le \mu(a) < 1.$$

Comment: This is known as the ``weak Harnack inequality." You can find the version for positive super-solutions $\|w\|_{L^1(B_1)} < C\inf_{B_{1/2}}w$ in Gilbarg-Trudinger, Chapter 8. Applying this to $w = 1-u$ gives the result.

Comment: @ConnorMooney Thank you. Why does it follow by taking $w=1-u \ $ ?

Comment: $a = |\{w \geq 1\}| \leq \|w\|_{L^1} \leq C\inf_{B_{1/2}}w = C(1-\sup_{B_{1/2}}u)$. If $\sup_{B_{1/2}}u$ is too close to $1$ (depending on $a$) there is a contradiction.