# A consequence of De Giorgi oscillation lemma

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde

The following lemma is true (see [DeGiorgi oscillation lemma](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313012/degiorgi-oscillation-lemma))

> Let $u$ be a subsolution of $$\mathrm{div}(A(x)\nabla u) = 0,$$
>   where $A$ is bounded, measurable and uniformly elliptic ($C^{-1}\mathrm{Id} \le A(x) \le C \mathrm{Id}$) in $B(0,1)$ such that 
>   $u \le 1$ and $|\{ u \le 0\}| =a>0$. Then $$\sup_{B_{1/2}}u \le \mu(a) < 1.$$

How does this lemma imply the following? 
 $$\sup_{B_{r/2}} u \le \mu \sup_{B_r} u$$
for $r<1$?

Comment: i assume it must be some rescaling and iteration??

Comment: @Math604 I also think this, but I'd like to see the details, which are not clear to me.